# Why do I get an error when I try to get HTML data from an attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<input type = "button" id = "someID" data-ddd='{"a": 1, "b": "2"}' onclick = "someevent(this)" />
```

Event implementation:

```
function someevent(element) {
    var d = $.parseJSON(element.data("ddd"));
    alert(d.a);
}
```

On this row:

```
 var d = $.parseJSON(element.data("ddd"));
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: element.data is not a function

Any idea why I get the above error?

Comment: `$(element).data(...)`? if `someevent` is literally an even handler, then the browser's JS engine is going to pass in a dom element, not a jquery object.

Comment: The error is completely correct.  No such function exists.

Comment: How can I get data value?Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `element` is a `HTMLInputElement` object. It doesn't have `.data()` method just like other `HTMLElement` objects. If you want to use the jQuery `.data()` method you should as first create a jQuery object:

```
$(element).data("ddd");
```

Also note that jQuery `.data()` method *tries* the `$.parseJSON` behind the scenes so there is no need to parse the datum, i.e. it returns the corresponding JavaScript structure:

```
function dataAttr( elem, key, data ) {
    var name;

    // If nothing was found internally, try to fetch any
    // data from the HTML5 data-* attribute
    if ( data === undefined && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
        name = "data-" + key.replace( rmultiDash, "-$&" ).toLowerCase();
        data = elem.getAttribute( name );

        if ( typeof data === "string" ) {
            try {
                data = data === "true" ? true :
                    data === "false" ? false :
                    data === "null" ? null :
                    // Only convert to a number if it doesn't change the string
                    +data + "" === data ? +data :
                    rbrace.test( data ) ? jQuery.parseJSON( data ) :
                    data;
            } catch ( e ) {}

            // Make sure we set the data so it isn't changed later
            dataUser.set( elem, key, data );
        } else {
            data = undefined;
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

If you use the `.attr()` instead of the `.data()` method then for parsing the JSON you have to use the `$.parseJSON` or `JSON.parse` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function someevent(element)
{
        var data=element.getAttribute("data-ddd");
        var d=JSON.parse(data);
        alert(d['a']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made some modification in your code

Try this

```
<input type="button" id="someID" data-ddd='{"a": 1, "b": "2"}' />

$("#someID").click(function() {
    var d = $(this).data("ddd");
    alert(d.a);
});
```